Correct Order of Steps Starting New Python Project on Windows
I've been eyeballs deep in pip, Jupyter, python documentation trying to understand how these components interact in a single project on the Windows OS.

Where in the folder tree and when do I tutorial_env\Scripts\activate?
Where in the folder tree and when do I pip install [package name]?
Where in the folder tree and when do I jupyter notebook?

My current folder tree has tutorial_env as the parent with the Lib folder and my main project folder as siblings within the virtual environment. I've pip install [package name] for all of my packages and can see those files in the Lib folder. When I import them into my main.py file within the main project folder, the first import statement gives a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'.
Seems reasonable that I need to rearrange my files. How do the pros do it?

If your getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' , it typically indicates that Python is not looking in the correct location for the installed modules or you haven't installed them. This can happen if the virtual environment in which the packages were installed is not activated, or if you're inadvertently using a different Python interpreter when your trying to run your code. To check that the environment is activated in the script your running you can look at the command prompt prefix or use where python in the terminal. This command should give you the path tot he python interpreter your using.
Going into your questions all of those commands should be run from the root/parent directory tutorial_env. First got into parent directory it would look like this from the command prompt. Replace Desktop\...\tutorial_env with the path to the parent folder.
cd Desktop\...\tutorial_env

Then create a virtual environment. I'm assuming you have already done this.With env being the name of the virtual environment.
python -m venv env

Activate the environment.
env\Scripts\activate

Then you can pip install your dependencies/libraries into that virtual environment.
The folder structure might look something lie this:
tutorial_env/
├── env/                   # Virtual environment
├── src/                   # Source files like Python scripts
│   └── main.py
├── notebooks/             # Jupyter notebooks
    └── analysis.ipynb

The Lib directory you mentioned I dont think should be needed, the python environment should automatically created and manage the installed libraries/dependencies itself. Just ensure you're working within the activated environment.

When I python -m venv env, it creates a folder env with sub-folders: Include, Lib, Scripts, and a file called, pyvenv.cfg. When I pip install [package name], the package automatically gets ported into the Lib folder.
When I run where python, it returns a path that's nowhere near my project folder. However when I run, python --version from within my project folder, it gives me the version.

**EDIT: where python includes my project folder after I've activated the venv.
I'm not familiar with the folder structure you've provided. Is src the standard location for my code files? Where would the packages be in this structure?

src is just an example of where you can place your Python files; they don't necessarily have to be located there, but it’s a common structure. The installed packages will be under env\Lib\site-packages, though typically you shouldn't need to directly interact with this directory.

Navigate to the env\Scripts folder and ensure that there is a python.exe file there. Try running this small script directly in PowerShell with the virtual environment activated—there should be a green (env) on the left to indicate that it's active. Run this which should should output the location of the Python interpreter you're using:
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
You can also run a small script directly in the terminal, which should work if you're in the virtual environment and have installed numpy:
python -c "import numpy as np; a=np.array([2,2]); print(a)"
